# Change the soft limit on Stack using ulimit command

Tags: c, memory, stack

I am studying Stack Memory and I am trying to increase the Soft Limit. 
The commands that I found to do so are:

- Show the Stack size in KBs:

```
ulimit -s
```

- I can vary it using:

```
ulimit -s value
```

- The O.S. also sets a hard limit, i.e., a limit that the user is not allowed to set. the code is:

```
ulimit –H –s
```

I got on the output as answer the **unlimited** value and sometimes the value **-1**

My question is:

- Why **-1** is a handy value to mean **unlimited**?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand the question. What’s wrong with -1?

Comment: Why does sometimes the output of **ulimit –H –s** is **-1** and not **unlimited** ? Is there any particular explanation to represent **unlimited** as **-1** ?

Comment: What other values could you use?  0?  Since `-1` is represented by “all bits 1” on most machines, it makes some sense as a maximum value if viewed as an unsigned value.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is probably because -1 is the closest integer to 0 that is not 0. Anything that is 0 or greater than 0 will be interpreted as an actual value.